# Do I need to run the cmd to watch sass changes every time?

Tags: css, sass

Sass is pretty awesome, and because it is there is tons of info. I am just not sure about the most efficient way to just open my file and get straight to coding, I don't want to have to open cmd prompt change directories then run the cmd `sass --watch sass.scss:style.css` every time I reboot the computer.

Is there a way to make it permanent, I know if I start a new project I would need to re declare what file to watch and change, but in an existing project there has to be a permanent solution. Also (im sure ill come across this soon), if I break my sass files up, still only making changes to one css file, do I just run the same command `sass --watch anotherSass.scss:style.css`?

**SUMMED UP:** *What is the most efficient way to watch `.sass` changes, preferably without any web based programs. If it is actually more efficient to just run that cmd every time, thats fine, but I dont want to miss an opportunity to eliminate that step (id rather run the cmd than use a third party) simple stuff here, but I literally decided to get into sass today, to run more efficiently so knowing this would be great*

Comment: Why do you need to keep the watcher running if the Sass files are not actively being worked on?

Comment: You could add a batch script to get it to run the sass watch when your computer starts up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) makes using Sass simpler, especially since it has useful modules for things like resetting CSS, CSS3, image sprites etc. When starting a project I just do `compass init` and then `compass watch`, and then just create the `.scss` files as needed. Compass itself can be installed from ruby gems with `gem install compass`. That's probably as efficient as it gets.

Comment: But Compass still needs to re-run compass watch every time we start doing the projects after the pc is started.

Comment: There's no way to compile Sass on the client-side. If you really don't want to run any commands, you can try [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), but its features are more limited.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the watcher running by launching the command in background  and close your terminal :

```
nohup compass watch > compass_log.txt 2>&1 & echo $! > compass_pid.txt
```

To kill this process, you just have to use this command :

```
kill -9 `cat compass_pid.txt`
```

It can be practice if you don't want to launch the command "compass watch" each time.